# How to get The Max Expensive Product in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

My Question is:
I solved the class but still have stack in this method...

6. Add a findMostExpensiveProduct() method that searches a the most expensive product and return that project from the list of products of the buyer .

Notice: my Code for PurchasOrder class is:

So I need Help Please.

```
package midMalak;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PurchaseOrder {
private int OrderId;
private Buyer buyer;
private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

public PurchaseOrder(int orderId, Buyer buyer) {
    super();
    OrderId = orderId;
    this.buyer = buyer;
}

public int getOrderId() {
    return OrderId;
}

public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
    OrderId = orderId;
}

public Buyer getBuyer() {
    return buyer;
}

public void setBuyer(Buyer buyer) {
    this.buyer = buyer;
}

public ArrayList<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PurchaseOrder [OrderId=" + OrderId + ", buyer=" + buyer + ", products=" + products + "]";
}

public void addProduct(Product P1) {
    products.add(P1);
}

public double findMostExpensiveProduct(ArrayList<Product> products) {

}

public void removeProduct(Product ID) {
    products.remove(ID);
}
public double calculateTotalPayment() {
    double Toatl=0;
    for(Product P1 : products) {
        Toatl= P1.getPrice()+Toatl;
    }
    return Toatl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately, SO is not a coding service so that requires you to take the first attempt. As it's your first post, I will give you a hint so you can try and make things work: `products.stream().max(..)...`

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would do something like this to get this answer, although I am sure there are better ways of searching ArrayLists

```
public double findMostExpensiveProduct(ArrayList<Product> products) {
    double mostExpensive = 0;
    Product expensiveProduct;
    for(Product P1 : products) {
        if(P1.getPrice() > mostExpensive){
            expensiveProduct = P1;
            mostExpensive = P1.getPrice();
        }
    }
    return expensiveProduct; // or expensiveProduct.getPrice() for actual price
}
```

This is how I would do this in other languages. I have also assumed there is a class method getPrice to return the price.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double findMostExpensiveProduct(ArrayList<Product> products) {

// Assuming product has the getPrice method
double mostExpensive = products.get(0).getPrice();

// Iterate through the list of products
for(int i = 1; i < products.size(); i++){

// if the next item is more expensive, assign that value as the most expensive
if (mostExpensive < products.get(i).getPrice()){
mostExpensive = products.get(i).getPrice();
}

}

return mostExpensive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general to get the max of any numeric value in a list or array do the following:

- initialize `max` to the first element at index 0.
- starting with the second index (1) iterate thru the list and compare the current element to `max'.  If current is > than max, replace max with current.

If you want to save one or more values of the object or the object itself to be associated with `max` then you must also save those values when max is altered.

Note:  Sometimes it is not convenient to initialize `max` to the first element. So initialize max to the smallest value possible for that numeric type (e.g. `Integer.MIN_VALUE`).  Then iterate thru the entire list as above.

The same procedure can be used to find the minimum.  Just reverse your comparison sign and initialize, if necessary, to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Finally, this is the basic algorithm.  There are enhancements to the Java API such as `streams` which can facilitate the process.